# Jenkins - add JDK 11 to JDK list

Tags: java, jenkins, java-11

I need to build my application using Java 11.
However the dropdown menu stops at Java 9.

What do I do? OpenJDK is acceptable too.
I'm on the latest version of Jenkins.

Edit: as of now I've downloaded the binaries using `wget`, extracted them on the machine, and added a JDK `JDK_HOME` entry via Global Configurations.

Comment: Which version of Jenkins are you using?

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov Just checked, 2.164, but I can update immediately to 2.168

Comment: 2.164 should support Java 11, update won't hurt anyway. Please refer here: https://jenkins.io/doc/administration/requirements/jenkins-on-java-11/

Comment: @MikhailKholodkov but that's for running Jenkins itself with Java 11. I need to compile an application with it.

Answer (score 64, accepted):

I guess you are using the [JDK Tool Plugin](https://wiki.jenkins.io/display/JENKINS/JDK+Tool+Plugin).

Click "Manage Jenkins" > "Global Tool Configuration" > "Add JDK" (near JDK installations)

Delete the java.sun.com installer.
Just click "Add Installer" below and choose "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz"

Enter following:

Label: openjdk-11

Download URL: https://download.java.net/java/GA/jdk11/13/GPL/openjdk-11.0.1_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Subdirectory of extracted archive: jdk-11.0.1 (Optional subdirectory of the downloaded and unpacked archive to use as the tool's home directory.)

And "Save" the configuration

=> Use JDK label (openjdk-11) in your build job.

---

The download-link given above appears to be from a time when java 11 hadn't entered LTS;

Instead go to [Java Platform, Standard Edition 11 Reference Implementations](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11) which will provide you the download-link to the most recent release of the...

> [...] official Reference Implementation for Java SE 11 (JSR 384) [...] based solely upon open-source code available from the JDK 11 Project in the OpenJDK Community. This Reference Implementation applies to both the Final Release of JSR 384 (Sep 2018) and Maintenance Release 1 (Mar 2019).

... which as of this writing is: https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Comment: Yes, I'm using that plugin! That's basically what I've manually done now. Good to know it can be automatized. Quick question. What if Jenkins lives in a Docker container and it is re-started? Does this method always download a fresh copy?

Comment: Yes, until you use a persistent storage (mount point in container: /var/jenkins_home).

Or maybe use a local web server for faster downloads of JDKs.

Comment: For some reason when i put any string in label the installer can not execute and when keep the filed empty, works

https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/zaproxy-jenkins/w5m9stza7pU

Comment: The `label` field in this installer config is to restrict the labels that this jdk will be available on. Leave it empty to use it on all nodes.

Comment: You cannot upgrade your jdk11 version with that method (replace with 11.0.6 in the url doesn't work). And the link given by oracle requires authentication, you cannot paste the url .

Comment: I tried this but I get 
```Installer "Extract *.zip/*.tar.gz" cannot be used to install "Java SDK 11" on the node "Jenkins"```

Comment: @Giuseppe, the download-link appears to be from a time when java 11 hadn't entered LTS;

https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11 which will provide the download-link to the most recent release of the...
 _"[...] official Reference Implementation for Java SE 11 (JSR 384) [...] based solely upon open-source code available from the JDK 11 Project in the OpenJDK Community. This Reference Implementation applies to both the Final Release of JSR 384 (Sep 2018) and Maintenance Release 1 (Mar 2019)."_ 

... which is: https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Comment: I had provided my previous comment as an additional answer, but this got moderated into deletion.

Comment: The "JDK Tool Plugin" is now called "Oracle Java SE Development Kit Installer": https://plugins.jenkins.io/jdk-tool/

Comment: Thanks this has saved me a lot of time. For reference, this link contains the jdk archive versions at time of writing. https://jdk.java.net/archive/

Comment: for jdk 17 you can use https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk17/ri/openjdk-17+35_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Comment: URL for download other JDK without login required

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/java/openjdk/download#openjdk-11

Answer (score 9):

JDKs can be managed with JDK Tool Plugin which usually comes pre-installed.

- Go to "Manage Jenkins" > "Global Tool Configuration"
- Under JDK installations  click 'Add JDK'
- Delete the default installer and add an installer of type "Extract
  .zip/.tar.gz"
- Find a URL to a JDK archive in tar.gz or zip format.

OpenJDK 11 binary can be found in [jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11](https://jdk.java.net/java-se-ri/11)

**This is the setting I have for openjdk-11+28**

```
JDK name: OpenJDK-11
Label: (Keep this blank)
Download URL for binary archive: https://download.java.net/openjdk/jdk11/ri/openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz

Subdirectory of extracted archive: jdk-11
```

Here in my case openjdk-11+28_linux-x64_bin.tar.gz, did contain a **subdirectory** named `jdk-11`

If it's incorrectly set up you might see the error:

```
Error: JAVA_HOME is not defined correctly.
  We cannot execute /var/jenkins_home/tools/hudson.model.JDK/JDK-11/bin/java
```

Comment: You can define the gradle task like this: build -x test -Dorg.gradle.java.home=<jdk11_path>

Comment: In my case jdk11_path ==> /root/.jenkins/tools/hudson.model.JDK/OpenJDK-11/jdk-11