# My jenkins is taking default java version as 11, but i want to build my pipeline with java 8. How can i achive that?

Tags: java, docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

[image]I need to use Java 8 in Jenkins, but Jenkins is taking Java 11 is the default.

I tried changing the default Java path, from Global Tool Configuration, I updated it to JDK 8, bstill, Jenkins is taking the default version. Can someone please guide how to update it to Java 8
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can either (a) point Jenkins to the JDK path or (b) let Jenkins install a JDK. Depending on the Jenkins version, this an integrated functionality or works via the [jdk-tool plugin](https://plugins.jenkins.io/jdk-tool/).

From the screenshot, I would say, you tried (a), but pointed to a non-JDK directory. You could try to make sure that there is actually a JDK in the path you're trying to use.

If you try (b), you can click the *Install automatically* checkbox and select a JDK from the list.

There are also a few pointers in the answers to [Jenkins - add JDK 11 to JDK list](https://stackoverflow.com/q/55243120/12039)

Comment: HI Kariem, I can't use the Jenkins-install due to some security concerns. However I  have tried the path where JDK is there, but still I am getting errors as                     
           'usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.392.b08-2.el7_9.x86_64 is not a directory on the Jenkins controller (but perhaps it exists on some agents'

Comment: Hi @Aditya, the directory has to exist on the controller. Can you log into the controller and check if it exists? From the error message, I would say that you might be missing a leading "/", but it could also be that you missed it when copying it into the comments field here.

Comment: Sorry to ask silly one, but can you please tell me where the controller exists? I have logged in to the same server where my Jenkins is installed, I have given the path from Jenkins server only. Aslo, after putting '/' in end, it still throw the same error - '/usr/lib/jvm/jre-openjdk is not a directory on the Jenkins controller (but perhaps it exists on some agents)'